# How is supposed to work rufus-scheduler on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I'm trying to use rufus-scheduler gem on rails to setup some tasks (send a mail each hour). I installed the gem and created a `config/initializer/task_scheduler.rb` with:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'  
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new
scheduler.every("1h") do
    Rule.all.each do |r|
        RuleMailer.report_email(r).deliver
    end
end
```

But I can't understand what is the next step. How this will run? should I setup a cron? this is runned by the webserver? rails s, or rake task, or what.

I don't get it and I'm unable to found the information.

Answer (score 0):

That will run using `every`.

> Rufus-scheduler supports five kinds of jobs. in, at, every, interval
>   and cron jobs.

On https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler , it shows examples of the various uses, in a variety of blocks. If you want to use cron, it would look more like this `scheduler.cron '00 09 * * *' do` (straight from the example, not set to your interval).

Comment: I dont get it, I mean, I already did the "every" block but what will make that code executed? should I run a ruby script install something or what? I mean, is a .rb file, it must be executed in order to run, if is not executed it doesnt matter what code i have it will never run.

Comment: It should work like you have it in the initializer... Is it not?

Comment: Yes i have it on the initializer, so this is executed by the webserver?

Comment: I have waited for 2 hours and my task is not being called. I really really CANT understand how is possible that a piece of code got executed if there is NO other process that run it.

Comment: What I would do, for troubleshooting, is to set the interval to a much smaller duration. Also, write some information to the log before during and after the block, to see what is being run when. Alternatively, you may wish to explore one of the many other gems that accomplish the same task - at work we use foreman and bluepill, but you can find more at https://www.ruby-toolbox.com.